# Adobe Flash CS4: тормозит фильтр

Tags: flash

Помогите при использовании фильтра свечения на 4 прямоугольника и моушин твин для того, чтоб они мерцали. Жутко тормозит этот эффект. Не могу понять, тормозит, потому что ему так сложно это обрабатывать или я что-то не правильно делаю.

Answer (score 1):

- Как именно моушен твин анимирует фильтр?
- Выложите проект, где-нибудь для анализа, посмотрим.
- Если не хотите, соберите тестовый проект с этими прямоугольниками, и если будет глючить, значит, проблема не в проекте (ну и выложить).

Comment: Создал новый проект, там создал 200х200 синий квадрат, применил alpha 56%, применил motin tween на первом кадре, поставил настройки для свечения по х и у 255 силу на 100%, на последнем - 300%. Он стал маленько тормозить, добавить еще четыре - станет еще больше. Я просто не могу понять, он вообще не должен тормозить нисколько.

Comment: Хм ... убедитесь, что у вас стоит аппаратное ускорение для флеша.

Comment: как убедиться?Оно автоматически устанавливается с Adobe Flash CS4

Comment: В браузере на любой флешке, правой кнопкой - "параметры",
в паблиш свойствах проекта - там где-то же есть галочка.

Comment: У меня стоит галочка.

Comment: Выложите скомпиленную флешку, а лучше проект. А попробуйте поставить x y = 10, силу = 10%.